# Proportionality between the expectation of the minimum of $N$ lognormal variables and the expectation of the lognormal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am investigating the relationship between the expectation of the minimum of $N$ independent and identically distributed lognormal variables, $E[M]$, and the expectation of the lognormal distribution, $E[X]$. Based on my numerical simulations, it seems that there is an approximate proportionality between these expectations for fixed parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. However, I have not been able to find an analytical proof for this proportionality.

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$ be i.i.d. lognormal random variables with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and let $M = \min(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N)$. I am interested in the following ratio:
\begin{gather*}
\frac{E[M]}{E[X]} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)} m N \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\ln m - \mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right) \right)\right)^{N-1}\\
\cdot \frac{1}{m\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln m - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,dm
\end{gather*}

My numerical simulations suggest that this ratio is approximately constant for any values of $\mu$, if $\sigma$ and $N$ are fixed.

In other words, it is saying that the following expression
\begin{gather*}
\frac{d}{d\mu} \frac{E[M]}{E[X]} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi \sigma^2} 2^{-N} e^{-\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} - \frac{(\mu - \ln m)^2}{\sigma^2}} N \left(1 + \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\mu - \ln m}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)\right)^{-2 + N} \cdot\\
\left(2 (-1 + N) + \frac{1}{\sigma} \left(e^{\frac{(\mu - \ln m)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \sqrt{2\pi} \left( -2 + \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{\mu - \ln m}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) \right) (\mu + \sigma^2 - \ln m) \right)\right)\,dm \equiv 0
\end{gather*}

holds for all $\mu$, $\sigma$ and $N$.

Is there an analytical proof or explanation for this approximate proportionality? Or is there any literature discussing this phenomenon? I would appreciate any insights or references.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is confusion in the notation for $Q$ and $N$

Comment: Thanks @Snoop, this is fixed.

Comment: Ok. So are you claiming that, if $\mu,\sigma$ are fixed, then $E[M_N]/E[X]$ is constant in $N$?

Comment: I was claiming that, if $\sigma$ and $N$ are fixed, $E[M_N]/E[X]$ is constant in $\mu$. This constant value is depending on the values of $\sigma$ and $N$. I updated the problem statement to make it more clear @Snoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom=}}\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}$A change of variable for $\dfrac{E(M)}{E(X)}$ suffices:\begin{align*}
&\peq \int_0^{+\infty} mN \paren{ \frac{1}{2} \paren{ 1 + \erf\paren{ \frac{ \ln m - \mu }{ \sqrt{2} \sigma } } } }^{ N - 1 }\\
&\peq \cdot \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2\pi} m\sigma } \exp\paren{ -\frac{1}{ 2\sigma^2 } (\ln m - \mu)^2 } \cdot \exp\paren{ -\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 } \,\d m\\
&= \frac{N}{ \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } \exp\paren{ -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 } \int_0^{+\infty} \paren{ \frac{1}{2} \paren{ 1 + \erf\paren{ \frac{ \ln m - \mu }{ \sqrt{2} \sigma } } } }^{ N - 1 }\\
&\peq \cdot \exp\paren{ -\frac{1}{ 2\sigma^2 } (\ln m - \mu)^2 } \cdot \e^{-\mu} \,\d m\\
&= \frac{N}{ \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } \exp\paren{ -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 } \int_0^{+\infty} \paren{ \frac{1}{2} \paren{ 1 + \erf\paren{ \frac{ \ln n }{ \sqrt{2} \sigma } } } }^{ N - 1 } \exp\paren{ -\frac{ (\ln n)^2 }{ 2\sigma^2 } } \,\d n,
\end{align*}
where $n = m\e^{-\mu}$.

Comment: But that result does not look independent of $\mu$, right?

Comment: @leonbloy It does, as this is the very change of variable.

Comment: Of course, I missed that $n$ was a dummy integration variable.

Comment: Thanks @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ, I think this is the proof. Just a follow up question, for distributions that have this kind of property (expected value of minimum of N iid variables is proportional to expected value of those variables), what condition should those distributions satisfy? In other words, what is the sufficient condition for a distribution such that this property holds?

Comment: @sophon That would better be asked in another post. I'd post my thoughts or even answers there even without a bounty :)

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ Thank you! Here is the other question that I just posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686774/proportionality-between-the-expectation-of-the-minimum-of-n-random-variables-a

Answer (score 1):

For a log-normal, changing $μ$
to $μ+c$
while keeping $σ$
and N
constant simply multiplies the values (and their minimum and the expectations) by $e^c$.

So you have $\dfrac{E[e^cM]}{E[e^cX]}=\dfrac{E[M]}{E[X]}$ as you have observed.

You would get a similar result for any other random variable when multiplied by a positive constant $k$, providing the expectations exist.  This multiplication would not change the scale-free coefficient of variation (standard deviation divided by mean) either.