# Proportionality between the expectation of the minimum of $N$ random variables and the expectation of the distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Inspired by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673042/proportionality-between-the-expectation-of-the-minimum-of-n-lognormal-variable), where it is proven that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$ are i.i.d lognormal random variables with parameter $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then the expectation of the minimum $E[M] = E[\min(X_1, \ldots, X_N)]$ is proportional to $E[X]$ given $\sigma$ and $N$ being fixed.

Therefore I am wondering if there exists a more generalized theorem that extends this to a general distribution. In other words, what are all the distributions that have such property: where the expectation of the minimum $E[M] = E[\min(X_1, \ldots, X_N)]$ is proportional to $E[X]$ given $E[X]/\sqrt{Var[X]}$ (coefficient of variation) and $N$ being fixed.

I would appreciate any insights or references.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you seem to be saying is that if you have iid $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ with mean $E[X]$ and expectation of the minimum $E[M]$ and then consider (for a positive constant $k$) iid $kX_1,kX_2,\ldots,kX_N$ then each has expectation $E[kX]=kE[X]$ and the expectation of their minimum is $E[kM]=kE[M]$, keeping the proportionality.  That is obviously true.

Comment: For a log-normal, changing $\mu$ to $\mu+c$ while keeping $\sigma$ and $N$ constant simply multiplies the values by $e^c$

Comment: @Henry, thanks for the answer, that makes sense. However, for generality, keeping the coef of variation fixed doesn't necessarily mean linearly scaling each of the $X$? Although the reverse is true.

Comment: Indeed not: rescaling clearly works, but I would presume that changing the shape in some other way usually does not